# In EF how do I code the class to access the foreign key?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

EF 6, code first technique.

Two classes defined as:

```
Public Class SqlLayerTypeSet
  Public Overridable Property SqlLayerTypeSetID As Integer
  Public Overridable Property Name As String
  Public Overridable Property Desc As String
  Public Property ConferenceTypes As New List(Of SqlConferenceType)
End Class

Public Class SqlConferenceType
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Desc As String
End Class
```

After seeding the tables look, respectively, as this:

[image]
[image]

What do I add to `Class SqlConferenceType` so I can access the existing foreign key `SqlLayerTypeSet_SqlLayerTypeSetID` which points back to the `SqlLayerTypeSet` that `SqlConferenceType` is a member of.

When I add whatever it is supposed to be, will that require a new migration?

I had thought that EF allows you to define properties in the class using a convention that simply gives you access to the foreign key but doesn't actually change the table definition.  The way I have been trying to add a property to the class is actually adding another column in the table when all I really want to do is access the column that EF code first already created.

I know this is a basic question, but I just can't seem to find the right SO post that explains it to me.

**Added after initial post:**

This is the line I added that adds access to the parent:

```
Public Overridable Property SqlLayerTypeSet As SqlLayerTypeSet
```

But if I try to add a specific property for the parent's key such as:

```
Public Property SqlLayerTypeSetID as Integer
```

That creates the extra column.  Is it the case that the only property I can add to `Class SqlConferencetype` is the navigation property, and I simple have to retrieve the foreign key value using navigation as opposed to being able to define a property that simply holds the foreign key value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class SqlLayerTypeSet
  Public Overridable Property SqlLayerTypeSetID As Integer
  Public Overridable Property Name As String
  Public Overridable Property Desc As String
  <ForeignKey("SqlConferenceType")>
  Public Overridable Property SqlConferenceTypeID as Integer 'Foreign key property
  Public Overridable Property ConferenceTypes As New List(Of SqlConferenceType) 'Relationship property
End Class


Public Class SqlConferenceType
  Public Property ID As Integer
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Desc As String
  Public Overridable Property SqlLayerTypeSet as SqlLayerTypeSet 'Relationship property
End Class
```

Comment: fyi I added my `extra above` as you were posting this.  I will study what you have posted.  Thx.  It seems I was part way there.

Comment: Awesome, just so you know this question didnt get a lot of views as it was marked vb.net. If you have the ability to write your code in c# to ask the question and then revert back to compare. It will help a lot